# google map way points not removing using direction services

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

New Plunker demo:http://plnkr.co/edit/6tmesHnvN0onjJWBwZJX

```js
//Source and destination auto complete textbox binding
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
        var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('source'));
        google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function () {
            var place = places.getPlace();
            sourceLat = place.geometry.location.lat();
            sourcelng = place.geometry.location.lng();
        });
        var places1 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('destination'));
        google.maps.event.addListener(places1, 'place_changed', function () {
            var place1 = places1.getPlace();
        });
    });

var cnt = 1; var v = [];var autocomplete = [];
   var map = null;var usedIds = [];
    var insertControls = [];
    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
     var map;
    var sourceLat, sourcelng; var maxNumberOfTextboxAllowed = 5;
    var autocompleteOptions = {
        componentRestrictions: { country: "in" }
    };

 function initialize() {
       
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(sourceLat, sourcelng); //to center google map location on my source points.
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: mapCenter
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


//My method to dynamically generate textbox

 function GenerateSourceDestinationPoint() {
            if (cnt <= maxNumberOfTextboxAllowed) {
                var id = findAvailableId();
                var OrderingField = $("<div class='OrderingField' id='OrderingField" + id + "'/>");
                var LeftFloat = $("<div class='LeftFloat' id='LeftFloat" + id + "'/>");
                var RightFloatCommands = $("<div class='RightFloat Commands' id='RightFloat Commands" + id + "'/>");
                var upButton = $("<button id='navigate' value='up'>Up</button>");
                var downButton = $("<button id='navigate' value='down'>Down</button>");
                var fName = $("<input type='text' class='fieldname' id='Txtopt" + id + "'  name='TxtoptNm" + id + "'/>");
                var removeButton = $("<img class='remove' src='../remove.png' />");
                LeftFloat.append(fName);
                LeftFloat.append(removeButton);
                RightFloatCommands.append(upButton);
                RightFloatCommands.append(downButton);
                OrderingField.append(LeftFloat);
                OrderingField.append(RightFloatCommands);
                $("#FieldContainer").append(OrderingField);
                 var newInput = [];
            var newEl = document.getElementById('Txtopt' + id);
            var txtboxId = 'Txtopt' + id;
            newInput.push(newEl);
            setupAutocomplete(autocomplete, newInput, 0, txtboxId);
                cnt = cnt + 1;
            }
            else
                alert("Cant create more than 5 points")
        }

//Auto complete function bind to dynamic textbox

function setupAutocomplete(autocomplete, inputs, i,txtboxId) {
            insertControls.push(txtboxId)
        autocomplete.push(new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputs[i], autocompleteOptions));
        var idx = autocomplete.length - 1;
            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete[idx], 'place_changed', function () {
                if (marker[idx] && marker[idx].setMap) {
                    marker[idx].setMap(null);
                    marker[idx] = null;
                }
                marker[idx] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    icon: 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=' + '|FF776B|000000'

                });
                marker[idx].setVisible(false);
                var place = autocomplete[idx].getPlace();
                if (!place.geometry) {
                    return;
                }
                marker[idx].setPosition(place.geometry.location);
                marker[idx].setVisible(true);
                 var auto = document.getElementById(insertControls[idx]).value;
                 v.push(auto);
                 calcRoute();
            });
        }



//when generating new textbox i will use this function to find already removed textbox id.For eg if i have remove textbox 3 then i will assign Txtopt3 to this newly generated textbox.
  function findAvailableId() {
        var i = 1;
        while (usedIds[i]) i++;
        usedIds[i] = true;
        return i;
    };

    function removeId(idToRemove) {
        usedIds[idToRemove] = false;
    };
    //method to remove textbox from Dom
    $(document).on('click', "img.remove", function () {
            $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut(1000, function () {
                if (cnt > maxNumberOfTextboxAllowed)
                    cnt = cnt - 2;
                else if (cnt == 1)
                    cnt = 1;
                else
                    cnt = cnt - 1;
                var id = $(this).attr("id").substr(13);
                DeleteMarkers(id)
                removeId(id);
                $(this).remove();

            });
        });

//This function will be call when i will remove any route point from dynamic textbox and here i will remove that point from my v array and again i will re-draw my map from source and destination.
 function DeleteMarkers(id) {
        var removeMarker = id - 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
            if (i == removeMarker) {
                v.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
        calcRoute();
    }

//function to draw my route from source to destination connecting all way points
 function calcRoute() {
        var start = document.getElementById('source').value;
        var end = document.getElementById('destination').value;
        var waypts = [];
        var request = null;

        if (v.length != 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
                waypts.push({
                    location: v[i],
                    stopover: true
                });
            }
            request = {
                origin: start,
                destination: end,
                optimizeWaypoints: true,
                waypoints: waypts,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };
        }
        else {
            request = {
                origin: start,
                destination: end,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };
        }
        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                var route = response.routes[0];
            }
        });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places,geometry"></script>
<input id="maptype" type="hidden" value="roadmap" />
    <input type="button" onclick="calcRoute()" value="View on Google Map" />

    <br /><br />
    <label>Source</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="source" id="source">
    <br /><br />
    <label>Destination</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="destination" id="destination">
    <br /><br />
    <button onclick="GenerateSourceDestinationPoint()" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" >Add Points</button>
    <div style="border: 1px solid -moz-nativehyperlinktext;"></div>
    <div id="FieldContainer">
    </div>

    <br /><br />
    <div style="height:400px;width:1000px">
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </div>
```

I am using google map to define **source** and **destination**.

Now between this source and destination user can add 5 points in between source and destination.

for Eg:

1. Source is **Los Angeles**
2. Destination is **Chicago**

Between this source and destination user can add 5 any points(city only) which falls in between this Los Angeles to chicago.

I am having two Textbox :

- source(google auto complete feature)
- destination(google auto complete feature)

For Adding Route Points i am dynamically generating 5 textbox with all textbox having google auto complete feature.(this feature may be extended so process is dynamic):

when user will enter Source and Destination and click on button **View on Google Map** button i will show Path between source and destination.

> Note:After entering source and destination you have to click on this
>   button that is **View on Google Map** in plunker link.

Now after this user will define 5 route points for those dynamically generated textboxes and i will show this route points on the path of my source and destination.

So far i am successfully able to show my route points on source and destination path but only problem is when i am removing any route points then i am not able to delete that point from my source and destination path.

It still exist on my source and destination path with marker.

> Now when i delete any route point then marker is not removing from the
>   way points though path is updated correctly.

See below screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue **in the question itself** (not a link to an external site including your complete code)

Comment: It looks like your code is not using waypoints that are entered via the user iterface.  Is that the problem you are asking about?  Where in your code do you populate the `v` array you use for waypoints?  It really would be more useful if you posted a minimal example.

Comment: @geocodezip:the v array you are asking about is in setupAutocomplete function

Comment: There is no `setupAutocomplete` function in the posted code (at least in the question)

Comment: @geocodezip:v array i am using for way points as you can see in my calcRoute function

Comment: Please see my updated question

Comment: Where is the `v` array defined?  Where do you clear it when you remove the waypoints?

Comment: i have define v array globally and i remove value from v array in DeleteMarkers function as u can see in my plunker'

Comment: ***though path is updated correctly*** in your plunkr-demo the path will not be updated, the only thing that will be updated is the autocomplete(which will be removed)

Comment: I saw the issue he is facing, but I can not reproduce it with steps.. just keep playing with the `view on Google Maps` and adding places

Comment: I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: calcRoute is not defined` in your code snippet.

Comment: @geocodezip:so sorry.now check my new  plunker and source code.I am badly stuck in this issue and not getting any help regarding this

Comment: @Dr.Molle:i have updated my code to minimal and with latest plunker.can you please help me with this issue.i am badly stuck

Comment: @geocodezip:is my plunker and code correctly working now?

Answer (score 2):

its working, i changed at markerids for the first to `marker[idx].setVisible(true);` and the second to `marker[idx].setVisible(false);` now, run your code

Comment: Its been a year mate so i have forgotten what was this but still thank you so much foir the answer.Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me :)

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation on waypoints](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints),

> **The maximum allowed waypoints is 8**, plus the origin, and destination. Google Maps API for Work customers are allowed 23 waypoints, plus the origin, and destination. Waypoints are not supported for transit directions.

Which might explain why your program starts to misbehave when it had processed too many waypoints; Your app is not deleting the old waypoints correctly so it just ran out of quota and misbehave.

In short, the issue you are facing should be caused by the incorrect logic you use to manage your waypoints, and fixing your waypoints logic should also fix this problem. Hope it helps.